# VBA - Apply Filter With Partial Header Match

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I posted a question for a macro solution to applying a filter across multiple worksheets based on header match.

Link: [Loop Through Multiple Worksheets and Apply Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531902/loop-through-multiple-worksheets-and-apply-filter)

I require help with a partial header match and not just an exact match, because, some of the headers will not be an exact match for the criteria - i.e, some will have "STATUS" as the header, some will be "*prefix*_Status", others "CurrentStatus" and so on.. So I need to use the `Instr` function (Unless there's some better option) to find any header that contains the word **STATUS** but I cannot seem to figure out where or how to use it..

I have the current solution which throws the following error on the `Match` line:

> Type Mismatch

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count

         ' Begin the loop.
         For I = 1 To WS_Count

            Dim count As Integer, rngData As Range

            With Worksheets(I)
                Set rngData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion

                count = Application.Match("*STATUS*", Worksheets(I).Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

                If Not IsError(count) Then
                    rngData.autofilter Field:=count, Criteria1:="INACTIVE"
                End If

            End With

         Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible there is no match?  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27302794/2521004) for more info

Comment: It is quite possible, but if I try convert the Int which is "I" to a str then i get "subscript out of range".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.Match` returns an error when no match is found.  Your using `IsError` to check for errors but the code is stopping before that point.  You need to skip the errors so that you can catch them later in code.

Try adding: `On Error Resume Next`

Full Code:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer, i As Integer, count As Integer
    Dim rngData As Range

    ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
    ' workbook.
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count

    'If Application.Match finds no match it will throw an error so we need to skip them
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Begin the loop.
    For i = 1 To WS_Count
       With Worksheets(i)
           count = Application.Match("*STATUS*", Worksheets(i).Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

           If Not IsError(count) Then
               Set rngData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
               rngData.AutoFilter Field:=count, Criteria1:="INACTIVE"
           End If
       End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**Tested** on simple data set

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Portland Runner :)