# Paste the final output of my vba code as values

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code but it only pastes the formulas present I want to paste it as values and not as formulas.

```
Sub lastRow()
Dim wsS1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
Dim wsS2 As Worksheet 'sheet2
Dim lastR As Long, lastC As Long


Set wsS1 = Sheets("Instru Input")
Set wsS2 = Sheets("Process1")

 With wsS1
 lastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 4
 End With

With wsS2
lastC = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(3, lastC).Address).AutoFill 
Destination:=Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)

End With
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA I don't know how to paste the data as values I am not sure what to add to this code that it will only paste as values.

Comment: Maybe add `, Type:=xlFillValues` after the destination?

Comment: can you elaborate? on how and where this "Type:=xlFillValue" will come in that particular line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will do the trick. it not the high-level code ... but i think it will serve the expected output you can try this-

```
Sub lastRow()

Dim wsS1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
Dim wsS2 As Worksheet 'sheet2
Dim lastR As Long, lastC As Long


Set wsS1 = Sheets("Instru Input")
Set wsS2 = Sheets("Process1")

With wsS1
lastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 4
End With

With wsS2
lastC = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(3, lastC).Address).AutoFill 
.Range(.Cells(3,1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)


End With

Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first - put a dot before every `Range()` and `Cells()`, thus you would refer to `With wsS2` correctly. Otherwise it refers to the `ActiveSheet` or the `Worksheet`, where the code is - [VBA - Loop Through Multiple Worksheets and Apply Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531902/vba-loop-through-multiple-worksheets-and-apply-filter/49531985#49531985)

---

Concerning the question - a quick way to solve it to add the following line at the end:

```
.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lastR, lastC)).Value2 =.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lastR, lastC)).Value2
```

before the `End With`. It would turn the formulas to values quite quickly. Or use the option from the comment, adding `, Type:= xlFillValues after the destination:

[image]

Comment: didnt work , it is still inserting data as formulas and not values

Comment: "Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(3, lastC).Address).AutoFill .Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address), xlFillValues " i entered like this